# Transparent ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, iptables, proxy, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have an SSH tunnel defined in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  It contains:

```
LocalForward 0.0.0.0:8000 some-service:80
LocalForward 0.0.0.0:8001 some-other-service:80
```

I would still like to be able to access the tunnels via their original DNS names (e.g. `curl some-service` should still work, rather than having to use `curl 0.0.0.0:8000`)

In an attempt to do this I added the following to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.2 some-service
127.0.0.3 some-other-service
```

Now, I think, I need some `iptables` commands which will do the following:

```
When I see a request to 127.0.0.2:80 I should proxy it to 127.0.0.1:8000
When I see a request to 127.0.0.3:80 I should proxy it to 127.0.0.0:8001
```

Such that, `curl some-service` would resolve to `127.0.0.2` (via `/etc/hosts`, which would in turn be proxied to `127.0.0.1:8000` (via `iptables`), which in turn hit `some-service:80` (via the ssh tunnel)

---

Question: I feel like there should be an easier way to achieve this?  If not, what would the `iptables` commands look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iptables` command you would use in this case is:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Note that when using the above rule, you do not need to bind to the any address in your SSH config. You can just use:

```
LocalForward 8000 some-service:80
```

`iptables` handles the redirection to the default loopback address of 127.0.0.1.

---

I tested this using [ipify.org](https://ipify.org). They provide a simple API for returning the IP address requests are sent from (which I've redacted from the output).

These commands are all run on the SSH client machine with an active connection to an SSH server initiated with the following command:

```
$ ssh -L 8000:api.ipify.org:80 <remote host>
```

Here's the `iptables` rule:

```
$ sudo iptables -n -t nat -L OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.2            tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:8000
```

With the `hosts` entry in place, the SSH tunnel is used:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep ipify
127.0.0.2       api.ipify.org
$ echo $(curl -s api.ipify.org)
<remote host IP address>
```

With the `hosts` entry commented out, the SSH tunnel is not used:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep ipify
#127.0.0.2      api.ipify.org
$ echo $(curl -s api.ipify.org)
<client machine IP address>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  Apologies for not getting back to you sooner.  In the end I had discovered/setup a `rinetd` instance before you'd posted your answer.  At this point in time I'm likely to keep this setup, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer with the caveat that it is untested.  Ty!

Comment: Does the `rinetd` solution support the "transparent" aspect (i.e. are you able to execute `curl some-service` and have it proxied by the intermediate server)?

Comment: Yes.  `curl some-service` hits `/etc/hosts`, then `rinetd`, then `ssh tunnel`, and finally the `some-service` itself.  Additionally, `rinetd` has an added advantage (for me) in that it reads from `/etc/rinetd.conf` on startup, and so I don't need to remember to add/remove iptables commands on startup/shutdown of my tunnels.